# How do I run a Live Application on a Grid

Tags: grid-computing

I am using Delphi++, which is still in beta and the documentation is not very good, how do I make my live application that I created with Delphi++ run on the Grid/Cloud ? and how do my clients start using it on their computer ?

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I got an answer from ++Technologies. You have to create a box on box.net or mydrive.ch. Then point the grid component to this account. The Grid++ node will automatically add your box to the grid and your clients need to install Grid++ Client (or you can create your own Grid Client using the Grid Component). The Live Application is automatically depending on the box or computer status split into several part across the Grid. When end user runs your live app the grid decides on which machine a particular part in executed. Optionally your clients machine may also attach to the grid as process power and help power the grid.
Sounds very confusing but I got it working and the performance is just amazing.

Cheers.

Comment: Forgive us if we don't particularly trust binaries hosted on megaupload.  Please don't provide links like that in future.